# Calling a generic method with T type parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to build a method that will take a variety of numeric types and preprocess them for a second method. I am not sure if I should be simply overloading or using a generic method. I tried to use a generic method but the method does not seem to recognize the parameter type. The code is below. Can someone please explain to me whether it is better to overload or use a generic method in this case? Also, if I wanted to use a generic method to do this, how could I make it work? Thank you very much.

```
 public static class math
 {
      public static int nextpow2<T>(T a)
      {
           double w;
           if ( a.GetType() is sbyte   ||
                a.GetType() is byte    ||
                a.GetType() is short   ||
                a.GetType() is ushort  ||
                a.GetType() is int     ||
                a.GetType() is uint    ||
                a.GetType() is long    ||
                a.GetType() is ulong   ||
                a.GetType() is float   ||
                a.GetType() is double  ||
                a.GetType() is decimal
           ) w = (double)Convert.ChangeType(a, typeof(double));
           else
                throw new System.ArgumentException("Internal error in nextpow2: argument a is not a number!");

           return _nextpow2(w);
      }

      private static int _nextpow2(double a)
      {
           double index = Math.Abs(a);
           int p = (index > 1) ? (int)Math.Ceiling( Math.Log( index, 2.0) ) : 0;

           return p;
      }
```

I am calling the method as follows:

```
 int indx = 0;
 int p = math.nextpow2(indx);
```

The code fails to compile. I get the following error:

Internal error in nextpow2: argument a is not a number!

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use the non-generic signature `nextpow2(double a)`? Many of the types you want to support are already implicitly convertible to `double`.

Comment: I'd get very upset with someone changing my decimal to a double as well.

Comment: I am trying to make a general method. It is possible someone may pass in a parameter that does not have an implicit conversion to double and I want to catch that case.

Comment: Very good point on the conversion of decimal to double. Thank you.

Comment: Even if you're writing both the method and its calling code, it's good practice to imagine the method being used by a caller unaware of its internal implementation. In this case, the method is difficult to use because it imposes unknown rules on its input. If you want the method to operate on `double`, make the parameter type `double` and let the caller worry about ensuring the input is suitable.

Comment: @PBrenek As soon as you make it generic, you need to deal with say Tony trying to Pass a PointF struct to it. Perfectly reasonable thing to do from my consumer point of view, and when you throw an error telling me it's not a double, I am going to be confused why you made it generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either say

```
a is sbyte
```

or say

```
a.GetType() == typeof(sbyte)
```

but it makes no sense to mix it into `a.GetType() is sbyte`. You should get a compiler warning about that! For `a.GetType()` will be an object which derives from `System.Type` (actually it will be `System.RuntimeType`), and therefore it can never derive from `sbyte` (since `sbyte` is sealed, being a struct, and `sbyte` itself derives only from `ValueType` and `Object`).

A better solution than a generic method, is to have:

```
public static int Nextpow2(double a)
{
    ...
}
```

All numereric types except `decimal` are implicitly convertible to `double`. So with the above signature, you can use it the way you want:

```
int indx = 0;
int p = math.Nextpow2(indx);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Sure. You're checking whether a `Type` object is an `sbyte`, or a `byte`, etc. You're not checking whether the type *represents* the type of `sbyte` etc... you're asking whether the value *is* an `sbyte`. That's never, ever the case. (Which is why you're getting a compile-time error.)

You *could* use:

```
if (a.GetType() == typeof(byte) ||
    // etc)
```

But I probably wouldn't. I wouldn't make this a generic method *at all*. If you really want the functionality, I'd write:

```
private static readonly HashSet<Type> ValidTypes = new HashSet<Type>
{
    typeof(sbyte), typeof(byte), /* etc */
};

public static double ConvertToDouble(object x)
{
    if (x == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("x");
    }
    if (!ValidTypes.Contains(x.GetType())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("...");
    }
    return Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(double));
}
```

Note how this is doing *one* thing: converting the argument to `double`. There's no point in making it then call `_nextpow2` - it's easy enough for the caller to do that if they want to.

Additionally, you've written two contradictory things:

> The code fails to compile. I get the following error:
>   Internal error in nextpow2: argument a is not a number!

If it fails to compile (which is what I'd expect, btw) then you can't be running the code, which means you can't be getting the exception. You need to differentiate between *compile-time* errors like this:

```
warning CS0184: The given expression is never of the provided ('sbyte') type
```

and *execution-time* exceptions.

Also, both your class and method names violate normal .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Duh. That makes complete sense. I don't know how I missed that one. Might I ask why you wouldn't?

Comment: Also recommended, if you want to go down the route of "generic math": "Miscellaneous Utility Library", by Skeet (and Marc, right Jon?) : http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/

Comment: @PBrenek: You're really not writing a generic method in the normal sense. It's not like it can *really* deal with any type, and it's not like you're handling that value as a value of that type anyway - all you're doing is calling `Convert.ChangeType`. What benefit do you think there is to making it generic?

Comment: @JonSkeet: You are missing a return type! O_o ;p

Comment: Thank you. I will check this out. I simply want the utility not necessarily to use a generic method. I am not very familiar with using HashSet. I will study this.

Comment: @leppie: Feel free to just fix it yourself next time ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet: But you sometimes make big edits after answering, so I hesitate :)

Comment: @leppie: That I do, but you could be in and out in a jiffie for something like this :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet This is very nice information. Thank you. It is overkill for this problem but it is certainly something I did not know and need to learn. Also, thank you for pointing out the incorrect naming conventions. I will keep this information in mid for the future. Thank you very much.

Comment: If one has a generic method which only works on specific types and is never used by code which doesn't know what types it's working with, it would be better to simply use overloaded non-generic methods.  On the other hand, if one has a method `static T multiply<T>(T n1, T n2)` which explicitly handles different argument types, one can write a single method in the source code like `static square<T>(T n) {return multiply(n,n);}` and have it handle all of the types for which `multiply<T>` would be usable; if `multiply` just used overloads, `square` would have to do so as well.