# How to get the next higher power of 2?

Tags: c#, matlab, ilnumerics

I want transform the following Matlab code to C#:

```
nfft=2^nextpow2(nn);
```

where `NEXTPOW2(N)` means the next higher power of 2 in Matlab.

So how do we achieve the same function by ourselves in C# code or by the help of ilnumerics Lab.?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508319/calling-a-generic-method-with-t-type-parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2) is probably the most efficient way, also previously mentioned [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1322548/89706):

```
unsigned int v; // compute the next highest power of 2 of 32-bit v

v--;
v |= v >> 1;
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;
v++;
```

Comment: VERY GOOD EXAMPLE

Comment: If this is the answer that is best for you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
x = 129;
NextPow = round(2^ceil(log2(x))) % Gives 256 for x = 129
                                 % Gives 2 for x = 2
                                 % Gives 16 for x = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core you can use [`BitOperations.LeadingZeroCount()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.leadingzerocount?view=netcore-3.0) or [`BitOperations.Log2()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.log2?view=netcore-3.0) to get the most significant bit's position and then

```
return 1L << (BitOperations.Log2(nn - 1) + 1); // or
return 1L << (63 - BitOperations.LeadingZeroCount(nn));
```

if `nn` is `ulong`. Change 63 to 31 if `nn` is `uint`

The above bit operations are intrinsics that are mapped to hardware instructions so they're extremely fast